# Does Visual Studio 2010 Professional have Sequence Diagrams?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does Visual Studio 2010 Professional have the Diagramming support announced on the web?
Do I need to install the TS version to be able to get these features ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Microsoft website, only the Ultimate Edition of Visual Studio 2010 (full relaease not Beta) comes with the UML Modelling Tools:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison
(Under 'Architecture and Modeling' features)

Answer (score 2):

They're there -- the UML diagrams, if that's what you mean (at least in my version -- VisualStudio Team System 2010 Version 10.0.20506.1.Beta1).

Select File -> New -> Modeling Project.

Then in the Solution Explorer (the window on the right), right click on your Modeling Project (whatever name you supplied -- default is ModelingProject1).  Then select Add -> New Item -> Sequence Diagram.   (Or Activity, Class, Component, Layering, Use Case).

Comment: Yes that is what I noticed and added to the thread earlier. I found them to be missing from the Professional version of Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It's too early to get a definite answer: the phase when a product group defines the exact packaging and licensing is just beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Heard it is available in VS2010. But not sure about edition specific features. It is yet to declare.

Check this: [What’s new in Visual Studio 2010 Rosario](http://www.vikasgoyal.net/net/What's%20New%20in%20Visual%20Studio%202010%20Rosario.aspx)

Comment: I have been trying to reproduce what i see on people's blogs, but simply cannot find the right menu options. I am currently installing the TS version. I will post back once I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

The Modeling tools can be found in the TS Version of Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need Visual Studio Ultimate to create modeling projects. You can read modeling projects in Visual Studio Professional.