# Can I create UML Models and diagrams in Visual Studio 2010 Express or Professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can I create UML Models and class diagrams in Visual Studio 2010 Express or Professional edition?Where can I get required plugins?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted my answer, I was wrong... these tools are in the Ultimate Version. Also, I think your question has already been [answerd here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925095/does-visual-studio-2010-professional-have-sequence-diagrams)

Comment: @Steve:Okay...is there any other VS editions other than Ultimate version where I can generate UML class diagrams??Can I atleast download the plugin for this?Where can I get?